# Having difficulties to add sqlite3 into gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile, ruby-on-rails-5.1, gemfile.lock

I am having difficulties to run `rails server` command because of the following error:

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)

I found couple answers in Google ([Changing Sqlite3 to Postgresql Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443146/changing-sqlite3-to-postgresql-rails), [Ruby on Rails - “Add 'gem sqlite3'' to your Gemfile”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350837/ruby-on-rails-add-gem-sqlite3-to-your-gemfile), [Add ‘gem sqlite3” to your Gemfile](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/add-gem-sqlite3-to-your-gemfile/235538)...) but none of these answers work for me. I tried to manually change `gemfile.lock` values, tried to run `bundle` commands but still getting the same error. Moreover, I do have `sqlite3` in my `gemfile` under `:development, :test` group.

- Operation system: `macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4 Beta`
- `sqlite3` version: 1.4.0
- `pg` version: 0.20

PS: I am using `pg` gem in order to use database on heroku.

Here is my `gemfile`, please note, some of the `gems` were deleted to make the list look smaller and cleaner:

```
group :production do
  # Database
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'bullet'
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

Full trace of the error:

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6.1 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        80: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        79: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        78: from /Users/antons./Documents/Websites/Alvian/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        77: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        76: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
        75: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        74: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        73: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        72: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        71: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        70: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        69: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        68: from /Users/antons./Documents/Websites/Alvian/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        67: from /Users/antons./Documents/Websites/Alvian/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        66: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        65: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        64: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        63: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        62: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        61: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        60: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        59: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        58: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
        57: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
        56: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
        55: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
        54: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
        53: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
        52: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        51: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        50: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        49: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        48: from config.ru:in `<main>'
        47: from config.ru:in `new'
        46: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        45: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        44: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        43: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        42: from /Users/antons./Documents/Websites/Alvian/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        41: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
        40: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
        39: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        38: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        37: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        36: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        35: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        34: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        33: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        32: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        31: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        30: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
        29: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        28: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        27: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:73:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        26: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
        25: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
        24: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        23: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
        22: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
        21: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `block in execute_hook'
        20: from /Users/antons./Documents/Websites/Alvian/config/environments/development.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        19: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bullet-5.9.0/lib/bullet.rb:57:in `enable='
        18: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bullet-5.9.0/lib/bullet/active_record5.rb:16:in `enable'
        17: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        16: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
        15: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
        14: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
        13: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        12: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        11: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
        10: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
         9: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
         8: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
         7: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
         6: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
         5: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
         4: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
         3: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
         2: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_co
nnection'
         1: from /Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
/Users/antons./.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 's
qlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

In case you need a `gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM


remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6.1)
      actionview (= 5.1.6.1)
      activejob (= 5.1.6.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.1.6.1)
      actionview (= 5.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activeadmin (1.4.3)
      arbre (>= 1.1.1)
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (>= 1.9.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 4.2.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.15)
      railties (>= 4.2, < 5.3)
      ransack (>= 1.8.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (< 4.1)
    activejob (5.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)
    activerecord (5.1.6.1)
      activemodel (= 5.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)
      arel (~> 8.0)
    activesupport (5.1.6.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.6.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    arbre (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arctic_admin (1.5.2)
      activeadmin (>= 1.1.0, < 2.0)
      font-awesome-rails
      jquery-rails
    arel (8.0.0)
    aws-sdk (2.11.213)
      aws-sdk-resources (= 2.11.213)
    aws-sdk-core (2.11.213)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.0)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-resources (2.11.213)
      aws-sdk-core (= 2.11.213)
    aws-sigv4 (1.0.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.12)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    bullet (5.9.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.11)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (2.18.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    carrierwave (1.3.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    childprocess (0.9.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.4)
    countries (2.1.4)
      i18n_data (~> 0.8.0)
      money (~> 6.9)
      sixarm_ruby_unaccent (~> 1.1)
      unicode_utils (~> 1.4)
    country_select (3.1.1)
      countries (~> 2.0)
      sort_alphabetical (~> 1.0)
    crass (1.0.4)
    devise (4.5.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 6.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubi (1.8.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.62.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.10.0)
    fog-aws (3.3.0)
      fog-core (~> 2.1)
      fog-json (~> 1.1)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-core (2.1.2)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.58)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
      mime-types
    fog-json (1.2.0)
      fog-core
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-xml (0.1.3)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    formtastic (3.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
    formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
    friendly_id (5.2.5)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    google-analytics-rails (1.1.1)
    haml (5.0.4)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    haml-rails (1.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 6.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    has_scope (0.7.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1)
    html2haml (2.2.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    i18n (1.5.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    i18n_data (0.8.0)
    inherited_resources (1.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2, < 5.3)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 4.2, < 5.3)
      responders
    ipaddress (0.8.3)
    jbuilder (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.3)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-slick-rails (1.9.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    json (2.1.0)
    kaminari (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.1.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.1.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-core (1.1.1)
    lazyload-rails (0.3.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mail_form (1.7.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.2, < 6)
      activemodel (>= 3.2, < 6)
    meta-tags (2.11.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.0, < 6.1)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mime-types (3.2.2)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2018.0812)
    mini_magick (4.9.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    money (6.13.2)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 2)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.10.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    puma (3.12.0)
    rack (2.0.6)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.1.6.1)
      actioncable (= 5.1.6.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6.1)
      actionview (= 5.1.6.1)
      activejob (= 5.1.6.1)
      activemodel (= 5.1.6.1)
      activerecord (= 5.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.1.6.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_real_favicon (0.0.12)
      json (>= 1.7, < 3)
      rails (>= 3.1)
      rubyzip (~> 1)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (5.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 5.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 5.1.6.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.2)
    ransack (2.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
      i18n
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    responders (2.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    ruby_parser (3.12.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.9)
    rubyzip (1.2.2)
    sass (3.7.3)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    sexp_processor (4.11.0)
    sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.2.0)
    social-share-button (0.2.1)
      coffee-rails
      sass-rails
    sort_alphabetical (1.1.0)
      unicode_utils (>= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.0)
    temple (0.8.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.9)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.20)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicode_utils (1.4.0)
    uniform_notifier (1.12.1)
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin
  arctic_admin
  aws-sdk (~> 2.3)
  bullet
  byebug
  capybara (~> 2.13)
  carrierwave (~> 1.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  country_select (~> 3.1)
  devise
  fog-aws
  font-awesome-rails
  friendly_id (~> 5.2.0)
  google-analytics-rails (= 1.1.1)
  haml-rails (~> 1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-slick-rails
  lazyload-rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mail_form
  meta-tags
  mini_magick
  pg (~> 0.20)
  puma (~> 3.7)
  rails (~> 5.1.6)
  rails_12factor
  rails_real_favicon
  ransack
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  social-share-button (= 0.2.1)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working by updating `gemfile.lock`

Changed `sqlite3 (1.4.0)` to `sqlite3 (1.3.13)`.

**Update:**
Don't forget to specify your gem version in `gemfile`.
Example: `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'`, otherwise `bundle update` command will return an error.

Comment: I just stumbled over the same situation, after some `bundle updates`. Sounds like a real dependency bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

I also got it working after changing `sqlite3` to `sqlite3 (1.3.13)` in the Gemfile, and after that i run `bundle update`

in Gemfile: `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'`

After that i managed to get to the Yay! You’re on Rails! page